# haskell and large binary

Tags: haskell, io, binary, stm

When broadcasting BinaryString through a TChan, what gets copied the whole Binary or just the reference ?

---

if the whole binary gets copied how to send only the reference ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a reference is written to the `TChan`, the payload is not copied. It would be far too inefficient to copy all the data all the time, and since the data is immutable (in general, you can cheat), it is safe to only transfer references.

Comment: do you mean that the  references get copied by default or should i do it ?

Comment: It's the default, you need not take any extra measures. As mentioned, since the data is immutable, sharing it is safe, so there's no need to copy it.

Comment: Maybe s/the constructor/a reference/?

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes, certainly.

Answer (score 2):

To be a bit more precise than Daniel (and confirm Daniels suspicion in his comment): A pointer to the constructor of the BinaryString (do you mean ByteString?) is written to the TVar.

Let us confirm by checking the relevant code. `TChan` is built upon `TVar`, and uses `writeTVar` to write the value, whch is implemented in `GHC.Conc.Sync` (and re-exported by `GHC.Cont` and `Control.Concurrent.STM.TVar`):

```
-- |Write the supplied value into a TVar
writeTVar :: TVar a -> a -> STM ()
writeTVar (TVar tvar#) val = STM $ \s1# ->
    case writeTVar# tvar# val s1# of
         s2# -> (# s2#, () #)
```

The argument is just passed along to the function `writeTVar#`, which is a primitive operation which is implemented in `rts/PrimOps.cmm`:

```
stg_writeTVarzh
{
  W_ trec;
  W_ tvar;
  W_ new_value;

  /* Args: R1 = TVar closure */
  /*       R2 = New value    */

  MAYBE_GC (R1_PTR & R2_PTR, stg_writeTVarzh); // Call to stmWriteTVar may allocate
  trec = StgTSO_trec(CurrentTSO);
  tvar = R1;
  new_value = R2;
  foreign "C" stmWriteTVar(MyCapability() "ptr", trec "ptr", tvar "ptr", new_value "ptr") [];

  jump %ENTRY_CODE(Sp(0));
}
```

This wrap the following  code in `rts/STM.c`:

```
void stmWriteTVar(Capability *cap,
                  StgTRecHeader *trec,
                  StgTVar *tvar, 
                  StgClosure *new_value) {

  StgTRecHeader *entry_in = NULL;
  TRecEntry *entry = NULL;
  TRACE("%p : stmWriteTVar(%p, %p)", trec, tvar, new_value);
  ASSERT (trec != NO_TREC);
  ASSERT (trec -> state == TREC_ACTIVE || 
          trec -> state == TREC_CONDEMNED);

  entry = get_entry_for(trec, tvar, &entry_in);

  if (entry != NULL) {
    if (entry_in == trec) {
      // Entry found in our trec
      entry -> new_value = new_value;
    } else {
      // Entry found in another trec
      TRecEntry *new_entry = get_new_entry(cap, trec);
      new_entry -> tvar = tvar;
      new_entry -> expected_value = entry -> expected_value;
      new_entry -> new_value = new_value;
    } 
  } else {
    // No entry found
    StgClosure *current_value = read_current_value(trec, tvar);
    TRecEntry *new_entry = get_new_entry(cap, trec);
    new_entry -> tvar = tvar;
    new_entry -> expected_value = current_value;
    new_entry -> new_value = new_value;
  }

  TRACE("%p : stmWriteTVar done", trec);
}
```

And here we see that `new_value` is a pointer that is never looked at, and stored as such.